# Good data visualization to show the validity of the acquired p-value of the model through multiple sample simulations?

Tags: python, data-visualization, density-function

I have a python `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
id         value1        value2
1          4             -2
2          5             17
...
150000     42            13
```

and acquired the z-score of difference in two means between `value1` and `value2`, and also got the p-value:

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest as ztest

ztest(df.value1, df.value2, value=0)
```

where $z$-score was $1.796$, and the according $p$-value was $0.072$. My objective is to see whether I get the similar $z$-score and $p$-value even when I randomly subsample $n$ rows from `df` and run the $z$-test again. I have programmed to check a few subsamples with $n=300$, only to find out that the $z$-scores and $p$-values were quite fluctuating.

So I decided to do around 100 simulations of different random subsamples and check the distributions of their $z$-scores and $p$-values, and compare it to the $z$-score and the $p$-value of the entire dataset.

My question is, what would be the best way to visualize so that I can emphasize the validity of (or the lack thereof) the result from the entire dataset? Is there a better way to visualize than simply do a density distribution of $z$-scores and $p$-values, centered at the original $z$-score and $p$-value?

Comment: *Of course* you won't get comparable Z-scores or p-values when your subsamples differ in size from the amount of data in the original test!  It sounds like you might be attempting something like a *bootstrap* or a *permutation test.*  If so, please consult our posts on these topics--there are some good explanations of both.  But if not, could you explain what you are trying to accomplish?